# Python: print without overwriting printed lines

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have

```
for i in range(0, 11): print i, "\n", i
```

I'd like my python program to print this way for each for loop

1st loop:

```
1
1
```

2nd loop:

```
1
2
2
1
```

3rd loop:

```
1
2
3
3
2
1
```

I've tried using \r\n or \033[1A but they just overwrite the previous line. Is there a way I can "push" the outputted line down so I don't overwrite it?

Comment: How about storing it in a list and print the list items at the end?

Comment: just a tip: you can just do `for i in range(11)`. You can do that whenever you want range to start at 0.

Comment: Create two lists, one with the original data and one with the reversed, concatenate and print. `a=[1,2,3]; aa=a+a[::-1]; for i in aa: print i`

Comment: You need some advanced console library, which may depend on your OS. Try [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) for a start if you have Linux or OSX

Comment: Do you want to print each loop in the way you mentioned above or just the last loop? I come answered with one solution for printing each loop but now I don't know if that is what you want, as other answers prints only the last loop.

Comment: As far as I understand from the question I think the OP is asking to print every loop: Loop 1: `1,1`; Loop 2:`1,2,2,1`; Loop 3:`1,2,3,3,2,1`

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this,

```
def foo(x, limit):
        if x < limit :
                print x
                foo(x + 1, limit)
                print x

foo(1, 11)
```

Comment: This might not be the best way to do it but it is in-line with the way you were trying to solve this.

Comment: I think the OP is asking to print every loop: Loop 1: `1,1`; Loop 2:`1,2,2,1`; Loop 3:`1,2,3,3,2,1`

Comment: Possible not only one method. The are a lot of ways to the dzen :-)

Comment: @jessag Well, that is what you will get if you call `foo` in a loop with `limit` as the loop variable.

Comment: @Sdwdaw This is definitely not the only method and I don't claim it to be the best either :)

Comment: @MohammadGhazanfar, I see it now. Cool solution then.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it in 1 for loop as you're currently trying.

As I suggested, you can do it like this by using lists

```
>>> l1 = []
>>> l2 = []
>>> for i in range(0, 11):
...   l1.append(i)
...   l2 = [i] + l2
>>> l1.extend(l2)
>>> for i in l1:
...  print i

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation of two list generators.

```
>>> ladder = [x for x in range(5)] + [x for x in range(5,-1,-1)]
>>> ladder
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> for x in ladder:
...     print x
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
4
3
2
1
0
>>>
```

Comment: I think '5' should be printed twice

Comment: just replace first `range(6)`.

Comment: I mean, each value should be printed twice. If I change to `range(6)` then `6` is printed only once... isn't it?

Comment: No. Just copy my code to your IDe and launch it. range(start,stop,step). Stop is not included into range. range(6) gives you values from zero to five. Six is not included.

Comment: In your anwser, `range(5,-1,-1)` starts printing `5` and `range(5)` prints until `4`, then `5` is printed once. You would have to change the reverse list to `range(4,-1,-1)` so 5 is not printed. Anyway, I like your solution.

Answer (score 0):

one of ways to solve this

```
def two_side_print(start, end):
    text = [str(i) for i in range(start,end)]
    print '\n'.join(text), '\n', '\n'.join(reversed(text))

two_side_print(1, 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to save the printed values in a list and print that list in reverse order in each loop iteration.

My suggestion:

```
l = []

for i in range(1, 5):
    print 'Loop '+str(i) # This is to ease seeing the printing results

    for val in l:
        print val

    print i
    l.insert(len(l),i)

    for val in reversed(l):
        print val
```

The output for a loop iterating from `0` to `5`:

```
Loop 1
1
1
Loop 2
1
2
2
1
Loop 3
1
2
3
3
2
1
Loop 4
1
2
3
4
4
3
2
1
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to help here:

```
def print_both_ways(start, end):
    print(start)
    if start != end:
        print_both_ways(start+1, end)

    print(start)
```

Usage:

```
print_both_ways(1,3) # prints 1,2,3,3,2,1 on separate lines
```